# Always Asked to Configure Firewall for iTunes

Tags: itunes, settings, system-settings, firewall

Whenever I open iTunes, I get the standard OS X dialog, 
`Do you want the application "iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?`
Every time I click allow, but I am asked the same thing without fail the next time I open iTunes.

In the Advanced section of the Firewall tab of the Security System Preferences pane, I see that iTunes is in fact set to allow. Changing the firewall settings makes no difference.

Any ideas for how to get this setting to stick?

Comment: do you look at this: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9936677 ?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Thanks for the link. I tried what they suggested, and eventually fixed it with a reinstall of iTunes. Post as an answer and I'll accept you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at Am1rr3za's article, and eventually it just said to reinstall iTunes, which I did.
That worked.
Am1rr3za, post as an answer if you want the points. Otherwise, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Starcraft II (a >10GB game) is doing this to me… I have to reinstall? :O </3