# How to stop being asked the same Firewall related question each time iTunes launches

Tags: itunes, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Always Asked to Configure Firewall for iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/always-asked-to-configure-firewall-for-itunes)

Every time I open iTunes (version 10.6) I'm asked "Do you want the application “iTunes.app” to accept incoming network connections?"

If I reply 'allow', iTunes works normally. (Except that I'm asked the same question again next time I launch iTunes.) If I choose 'deny' I get a similar dialog box asking me to attend to my Firewall settings the next time I open iTunes.

I've already added it to the list of apps which, under Firewall settings, are allowed to accept incoming network connections. I've tried removing and adding it again to no avail.

How can I stop this dialog box holding up the launch of iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest double checking all steps have been followed at:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2553